# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'fuzzables' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, fuzzer

I have problem with python script. When I try to run it with some parameters, I get following error:

```
  print json.dumps(filter(lambda x: x.get('url'), [x.as_dict() for x in fuzzables]), indent=4)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'fuzzables' referenced before assignment
```

I am not a python guy; can someone help me?

The code:

```
def main():
    form_stack = []
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser('crawl')
    parser.add_argument('url', type=str, help='Target URL')
    parser.add_argument('-s', '--strict', action='store_true', help='Strict Mode')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    target = get_final_url(args.url)
    ltarget = [target]

    if args.strict:
        br = Browser(qapp=qapp, scope=ltarget, strict_match=target)
    else:
        br = Browser(qapp=qapp, scope=ltarget)

    br.load(target)

    dom_urls = br.get_history(clear=True, verify=True)
    static_urls = br.urls(verify=True)
    static_urls.extend(dom_urls)
    static_urls = list(set(static_urls))

    already = 0

    for url in static_urls:
        already += 1
        if len(static_urls) >= 128:
            break

        try:
            br.load(url, retries=2)
        except BrowserTimeout, e:
            continue

        form_stack.extend(br.forms())
        temporaries = br.urls(verify=True)

        map(lambda x: static_urls.append(x), temporaries)
        dom_urls = br.get_history(clear=True, verify=True)
        s_urls = br.urls(verify=True)
        s_urls.extend(dom_urls)
        s_urls = list(set(s_urls))
        static_urls.extend(s_urls)
        static_urls = list(set(static_urls))
        static_urls = map(make_dummy_url, static_urls)
        fuzzables, hashsums = [], []

        for form in form_stack:
            if form['hashsum'] in hashsums:
                continue
            else:
                hashsums.append(form['hashsum'])

            method = form.get('method', 'POST')
            action = form.get('action', '')
            headers = form.get('headers')
            cookies = form.get('cookies')
            data = unquote(urlencode(form.get('fields', {})))
            action = action.toString() if type(action) != str else action

            if type(data) == str and "__PAYLOAD__" not in data:
                data = parse_qsl(data)
                [data.update(set_payload(x)) for x in data.keys()]
                data = unquote(urlencode(data))

            method = method.upper()
            vhost = urlparse(action).hostname
            fuzzable = Fuzzable(method, action, data, cookies, headers, vhost)
            fuzzables.append(fuzzable)

        for url in static_urls:
            url = url.toString() if type(url) != str else url
            uu = urlparse(url)
            qsl = urlparse(url)
            qsl = parse_qsl(uu.query)

            [qsl.update(set_payload(x)) for x in qsl.keys()]
            qsl = urlencode(qsl)

            qq = "?%s" %qsl
            qq = "" if qq == "?" else qq
            url = "%s://%s%s%s" %(uu.scheme, uu.netloc, uu.path, qq)

            if "__PAYLOAD__" not in url:
                continue

            cookies = br.get_plain_cookies()
            vhost = urlparse(url).hostname
            fields = ""
            headers = {}
            fuzzable = Fuzzable("GET", url, fields, cookies, headers, vhost)
            fuzzables.append(fuzzable)

    """
    fu = urlparse(target)
    path = fu.path
    query = parse_qsl(fu.query)
    [query.update(set_payload(x)) for x in query.keys()]
    query = unquote(urlencode(query))
    rqury = "?%s" %query
    rqury = "" if rqury == "?" else rqury
    temporary_url = "%s://%s%s%s" %(fu.scheme, fu.netloc, path, rqury)
    fields = ""
    cookies = br.get_plain_cookies()
    vhost = urlparse(target).hostname
    headers = {'host': fu.hostname}
    fuzzable = Fuzzable("GET", temporary_url, fields, cookies, headers, vhost)
    fuzzables.append(fuzzable)
    """

    br.close()
    del br

    print json.dumps(filter(lambda x: x.get('url'), [x.as_dict() for x in fuzzables]), indent=4)
```

Comment: Is there more to this script?  You have not assigned any value to `fuzzables` in the above.

Comment: Here it is -  https://github.com/zulla/ritalin, filename ritalin_crawl.py, line 154.

Answer (score 1):

`fuzzables` is only assigned to in a loop:

```
for url in static_urls:
    # ...
    if len(static_urls) >= 128:
        break

    # ...

    fuzzables, hashsums = [], []
```

If `static_urls` is empty or contains more than 128 items, the assignment line is never reached, and `fuzzables` remains unbound.

Assign something to `fuzzables` **outside** of that loop if you want to guarantee it is bound.

Glancing over that code, you probably do *not* want to create a new, empty `fuzzables` for each `static_urls` entry either.

Answer (score 1):

Given the script linked in the comments, if `static_urls` is an empty list, then no assignment is ever made to `fuzzables`, so the variable is undefined when referenced.

You could move the `fuzzables = []` assignment outside of the `static_urls` loop.

Answer (score -1):

The error message seems to indicate the problem.  You need to assign something to `fuzzables` before you use it.

For example:

```
fuzzables = #something
```

Comment: There was nothing there to read when I answered.  My answer is still correct though.